# Supporting magento 1 LTS

Tags: discussion

There is a tag [magento-1-lts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1-lts) that at the moment is attached to a single question.
This is meant to denote questions about the magento 1 fork called **Magento 1 Long Term Support** [found here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/).
This **IS NOT** an official magento 1 version but the guys at OpenMage promise to keep this version patched and fixed long after Magento 1 is officially not supported anymore (Q4 2018).
Even though I approve of this initiative, I think this does not qualify as an accepted topic on magento.stackexchange.com.
I feel this opens doors for everyone that creates an unofficial Magento 1 fork to have it listed in here. And I think this is not good for the website itself.
But I want to ask the community... **What do you feel about allowing questions about magento-lts in here?**

Please don't offer single row answers "Yes, we should allow magento-lts questions" / "Magento-lts questions should be off topic".
Explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is too early to say anything about it now, whether there will be one high quality highly maintained fork or several.

I do think we should allow questions about this forking/community LTS thing in general, but not about the contents of specific forks. I don't think Magento SE is the right place to ask questions about changes/fixes/policies/bugs etc. of these forks. OpenMage is maintained on GitHub and has an "issues" page there. Questions should be asked there.

We will see how this evolves and if there is action needed to arrange something here on Magento SE for these forks.

Answer (score 2):

#### What do you feel about allowing questions about `magento-lts` in here?

No, not now. Magento 1 support still persists. So in my opinion, a question related to `magento-lts` will come under off-topic since we can consider this as an open source third party software.

So questions related to `magento-lts` should be voted to close as off-topic unless if sufficient code example is not there.

But after Magento 1 support freezes, I think we need to allow questions from this open source instead of closing them instantly if it is community supported Magento 1 source (unofficially).

#### Whether we need to keep this tag ?

Now, this is a special case. Why `Magento-lts` is there first off all? since Magento 1 official support is going to an end. So before that, it is very important to communicate to developers and people around Magento community about this promising, one which is going to be an unofficial source for Magento 1, which is going to be a community-driven open software in future.

So if the tag for that helps to spread the news, then, in my opinion, we can just keep it.

I know that we already removed almost all third-party tags before. But this is not a third-party Magento module, but which is going to be the "future" of Magento 1 itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this tag with the intention to mark questions/bugs that are already fixed in "LTS fork" or are qualified to be fixed there.

IMHO magento-LTS is already better choice ... security patches are included backwards, making it easier to update for people with less technical backround. It includes fixes for age old bugs (missing image attribute in flat table, missing table prefix and some other), **but** after thinking about it, this is not the right place to point people there ...

**I'd agree to delete this tag.**

*Maybe, when LTS keeps its promise and continue support for M1 and there is no similiar fork, it can be added again.*